# Flutter App building from xcode but failing from android studio

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

After upgrading to xcode 15 if I launch my flutter app from android studio it fails to build but works on my iphone11 device. It also builds on the ios emulator if launched from xcode. I keep getting this error :

> Xcode's output: ↳
> ld: in /Users/macbook/Desktop/dis_or_dat/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-audio/lame.framework/lame(VbrTag.o),
> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,
> file
> '/Users/macbook/Desktop/dis_or_dat/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-audio/lame.framework/lame'
> for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> note: Using new build system
> note: Planning
> note: Build preparation complete
> note: Building targets in parallel
> /Users/macbook/Desktop/dis_or_dat/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
> deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'FMDB' from
> project 'Pods')

Comment: ld: in /Users/macbook/Desktop/dis_or_dat/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-audio/lame.framework/lame(VbrTag.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/macbook/Desktop/dis_or_dat/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-audio/lame.framework/lame' for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                                               Can you pay attention to this part of the log

Answer (score 0):

ios>open "Podfile"write  platform :ios, '9.0'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your project deployment target is set for iOS version 8 and later, you need to update that (iOS 9 should be minimum target).
Navigate to project's ios folder and open 'Podfile'. Uncomment the second line and set it to any later version than 8.
If the problem still doesn't get solved, this thread might help:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/96361

Comment: Doesn't solve it

Comment: @davidomu did you get to the bottom of this. I am having the same issue.  Builds in XCode not in AS. I have platform target set to 10 in podfile and Xcode.

Comment: @its_broke_again Nope I just continued using the actual device

Answer (score 0):

Commenting here for the unwary who like me, spent far too long trying to work out what was going on.

It turns out this is an issue with Flutter sound.  The app will build in XCode, and on a real device but not on a simulator.

Bug being tracked here:
https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/issues/775